# Count the number of matrices that maps a cube to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, geometry

Let $S=\{(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1)\}$ be the set of 8 vertices of a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. How many matrices $A$ are there such that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ is a bijective map that maps $S$ to $S$ and $|\det(A)|=1$? A matrix is regarded as a linear map in terms of matrix multiplication.

Comment: You can see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priori, we should not take for granted that $A$ respects the cube shape (e.g., maps edges to edges, diagonals to diagonals, faces to faces).
However, $A$ must map 
$$T:=\{\,\tfrac 12 s_1+\tfrac12 s_2\mid s_1,s_2\in S\,\} =\{\,(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\in\{-1,0,1\}\,\}$$
to itself. The same holds for the set $U$ of vectors $\in T$ that can be written as $\tfrac 12 s_1+\tfrac12 s_2$ in exactly four ways. 
One verifies, that $U=\{\pm e_1, \pm e_2,\pm e_3\}$. (The vertices of the cube can be written in one way, the edge centres in two ways, the face centres in four ways, the origin=cube centre in eight ways).

$e_1\in U$ must be mapped to some $v_1\in U$, for which there are $6$ choices. So the first column of $A$ has two entries $0$ and one $\pm1$.

$e_2\in U$ must be mapped to some $v_2\in U$, but linearly independent of $v_1$ (i.e., $\ne \pm v_1$). There are $4$ choices for this. So the second column of $A$ also has two entries $0$ and one $\pm1$, but in a different row.

$e_3\in U$ must map to some $v_3\in U$, but linearly independent of $v_1,v_2$ (i.e., $\ne \pm v_1$ and $\ne \pm v_2$).  There are $2$ choices for this. So the third column of $A$ also has two entries $0$ and an entry $\pm1$ in the last remaining row.

In total, this gives us $6\cdot 4\cdot 2=48$ candidate maps. and by Sarrus's rule it is clear that $\det A=\pm1$.